# Python unsupported operand type(s) for >>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've never used such code with streams:

```
print >>self._stream, indentation + line
```

Would like to look at the docs. Google wasn't good at searching ">>".
The question is - how to write it in Python 3?

It causes an error:

```
Python unsupported operand type(s) for >>
```

By default (in function) stream is `sys.stdout`

Comment: Could you give more details on the stream?  Is it used to write to a file?  Are you trying to write an error?  Are you trying to build a string?

Comment: Among other thing, `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: Besides, you can search signs in this site: http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>>` syntax prints the string to the given stream instead of stdout.

The equivalent in python 3 is the `file` keyword argument on the `print` function.

```
print('my text here', file=self._stream)
```